# Entity color as an if statement condition

Tags: javascript, if-statement, colors, conditional-statements

I am very new to JavaScript. The task I am working on is a simple game using boxbox as physic simulator. 
Anyway, I have 3 blocks that change colour when the player entity touches them. I would like to display a simple result message ("Only one? Try again!" sort of thing). However, I have no idea if the color value can be used as a condition. This is what I came up with:

```
function score() {
if (gold1.color == "gold" || gold2.color == "gold" || gold3.color == "gold") {world.createEntity(result, {
        shape: "square",
        x:9,
        y:4,
        width: 3,
        height: 2,
        image: "only1.png",
        imageStretchToFit: true, }
        }
else if (gold1.color == "gold" && gold2.color == "gold" || gold2.color == "gold" && gold3.color == "gold" || gold1.color == "gold" && gold3.color == "gold") {world.createEntity(result, {
        shape: "square",
        width: 3,
        height: 2,
        x:9,
        y:4,
        image: "only2.png",
        imageStretchToFit: true, }
        }
else (gold1.color == "gold" && gold2.color == "gold" && gold3.color == "gold") {world.createEntity(result, {
        shape: "square",
        width: 3,
        height: 2,
        x:9,
        y:4,
        image: "only3.png",
        imageStretchToFit: true, }
        }
}
```

I am not sure if this is a completely wrong approach or just a syntax error. Please help.

Thank you.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: I am not getting any errors.
The game is loaded into the canvas, and when I add this function, it doesn't load at all.

Comment: What kind of objects are gold1, gold2 and gold3?

Comment: They are all instances of same variable:
var block2 = {
 name: "block2",
 shape: "square",
 color: "orange",
 width: 1,
 height: 1,
 density: 20,
 onImpact: function (entity, force) {
  if (entity.name() === "player") {
   this.color("gold"); 
  }
 }
};

Comment: You're saying you don't get any errors in your console?

Comment: Use `[gold1, gold2, gold3].filter(function(g){return g.color=="gold";}).length`

Comment: I'm simply typing the code in the notepad, then open html file with the canvas where the game loads.

Comment: @user2983456 the console is part of the browser, not the text editor. Which browser are you using? I think most browsers support the debugging console via f12, but I think chrome has a very good native support for the console so if you're using chrome press f12. IE's console sucks and FireFox I think has a console, but I don't remember.

Comment: Unfortunately, I am using a separate the whole 'game' is in a separate .js file, that is being called by the html one. I am really sorry I cannot provide you with the answers.

Comment: @user2983456 you can inspect JS files by going to "Sources" tab in the  debugging console and finding the file in question...believe me this is better for you than it is for me. I couldnt imagine developing in JavaScript without the console.

Comment: Thank you for that tip! It did find an error that I do not understand: _Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {_ It is about this line of code: **else (gold1.color == "gold" && gold2.color == "gold" && gold3.color == "gold") {world.createEntity(result, {** I have checked and it should be correct, every curly bracket is in the place it should, both opening and closing ones.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a debugger in your browser (if you're using chrome, just press f12). Put a breakpoint before the code you posted executes. What values do you see in gold1.color, gold2.color?

I find the code you posted to be confusing based on the description you gave us. Why are you doing all these checks?

I'll edit my answer once there is more info..

Also another thing, it looks like your first code block will execute if the other two would execute, so why do you even have the "else if" statements? If any of the colors are gold, the first code block will execute, and the other blocks of code wont execute ever because they all require one or more of the colors to be gold.

Comment: No, since `&&` has a higher [precedence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator_precedence) than `||` it *is* already evaluated in that order, no parenthesis necessary.

Answer (score 0):

what about:

```
function score() {
    var nrGold = 0;

    if (gold1.color == "gold") {
        nrGold++;
    }
    if (gold2.color == "gold") {
        nrGold++;
    }
    if (gold3.color == "gold") {
        nrGold++;
    }

    if (nrGold!==0) {
        world.createEntity(result, {
            shape: "square",
            width: 3,
            height: 2,
            x:9,
            y:4,
            image: "only"+nrGold+".png",
            imageStretchToFit: true
        });
     }
}
```

note1: last property in json should not end with comma (see `imageStretchToFit: true,` in your code)

note2: you are missing closing bracket for `world.createEntity` function

Comment: This did not crash the game, it loaded just fine, but did not make the 'result' entity appear. 
Thank you for the notes, I will pay more attention now!